# при нажатии кнопки для воспроизведении аудио файла дает это окно. Flutter

Tags: flutter

[ Row(children: 
[GestureDetector(
onTap: () {
final pl = AudioCache();
pl.play("6.mp3");
},](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PW8BW.jpg)
вот код

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12120)